# Impala incompatible return types in case when statement

Tags: sql, impala

I am running an Impala query and try to use a case when statement:

```sql
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN typ_prtctn  = 2 then  0.5*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL  -- life insurance policies pledged
WHEN typ_prtctn  = 18 then  2*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL  -- equity and investment funds shares
ELSE PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL END as PROTECTION_VALUE
FROM database.tablename
```

It complains

```
AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'DECIMAL(38,9)' and 'DECIMAL(38,10)' of exprs '0.5 * PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL' and 'PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL'.
```

This however works fine:

```sql
SELECT *,
0.5*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL as test  
FROM database.tablename
```

As the error message indicates, `PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL` is of type `decimal(38,10)`. Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a curious problem, one that I would not expect.  A `case` expression returns a single type so all the conditions have to converted to the same time *within* the expression.

You can fix the problem with explicit type casts.  I'm not sure what the type should be, so I'll guess:

```
(CASE WHEN typ_prtctn  = 2 
      THEN CAST(0.5 * PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL AS DECIMAL(38, 10)) -- life insurance policies pledged
      WHEN typ_prtctn  = 18 
      THEN CAST(2 * PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL AS DECIMAL(38, 10))  -- equity and investment funds shares
      ELSE CAST(PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL as DECIMAL(38, 10))
 END) as PROTECTION_VALUE
```

I suspect this is happening because 38 is the maximum precision.  The multiplications are probably changing the precision/scale and because the value already has the maximum precision, there is a problem.  I would not expect this to generally happen with decimals.

Answer (score 1):

try force the cast for case as decimal

```
  SELECT *,
    CAST(CASE WHEN typ_prtctn  = 2 then  0.5*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL  -- life insurance policies pledged
            WHEN typ_prtctn  = 18 then  2*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL  -- equity and investment funds shares
        ELSE PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL END as DECIMAL(10,4) ) AS  PROTECTION_VALUE
```

or try apply the same data type to all the calculation  forcing a float (1.0 , 2.0 instead of 2*  and same value)

```
CASE WHEN typ_prtctn  = 2 then  0.5*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL  -- life insurance policies pledged
WHEN typ_prtctn  = 18 then  2.0*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL  -- equity and investment funds shares
ELSE 1.0*PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL END as PROTECTION_VALUE
```

Comment: I get a similar error using the cast: `AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'DECIMAL(38,9)' and 'DECIMAL(38,10)' of exprs '0.5 * PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL' and 'PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL'.`

Comment: same error  `AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'DECIMAL(38,9)' and 'DECIMAL(38,8)' of exprs '0.5 * PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL' and '1.0 * PRTCTN_ALLCTD_VL'.`